# Two-part for loop in C

Tags: c, c11

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

mentions

```
for ( declaration expression opt ; expression opt ) statement
```

under **6.8.5 Iteration statements**.

Is this a typo or does C11 have a two-expressions-in-the-parens **for** loop?

Comment: It doesn't look like typo, given it is in the separate line in addition to the regular three-part one. Probably the best thing is to try it.

Comment: I have. It doesn't work.

Comment: i think the next page explains it

Comment: @proton I don't see a clear explanation, though...

Comment: A declaration ends with a semicolon, so there are still three parts separated by semicolons.

Comment: @IanAbbott I see a single semicolon in this line. Or you mean the *declaration* is expanded into semicolon-ending expression?

Comment: it says: `Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted`

Comment: @IanAbbott Actually yes, the *declaration* syntax is given in `6.7`, including the semicolon.

Comment: Sometimes the excess formalism is confusing.

Comment: @proton I think when §6.8.5.3 discusses _clause-1_ as a declaration, I think it means everything up to the terminating semicolon of the declaration.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, §6.8.5.3 makes it clear that two semicolons are required even though the formal syntax seems confusing. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all about syntax. 6.8.5 gives two forms of for loops:

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

The 2nd version refers to the case where you declare loop iterator variables, new since C99.

Now if we look at what the syntax for *declaration* means, it is found in 6.7:

```
declaration:
  declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
```

Note the semicolon at the end - it requires a semicolon as part of the syntax. Copy/paste the syntax into the 2nd version of the for loop and you get this:

```
for (declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt )
```

Comment: You can think of syntax statements as if they were pre-processor macros, if that helps :)  Simple text replacement.

Comment: And this wrangling is required because a declaration is not an expression. Of course, the formal grammar could have been written a bit more clearly, so that exactly the OP's question would not arise.

Answer (score 2):

In following page of n1570, we can see:

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement
>   The statement
>   `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement`
> ...

and later that clause-1 can be a declaration or an expression

And in  6.7 Déclarations, we can see:

> Syntax
> declaration:
>   declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;

My understanding is that the *declaration* part includes the first semicolon. For example in `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)`

- `int i=0;` is the declaration
- `i<10` is the first optional expression
- `i++` is the second optional expression